# react native : Create component to minimize lines of code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, jsx

In my example I am trying to create a component called `nextButton` from the following code and then I can use it.
Where's the problem with what I did?

```
export const MainScreen = () => {

const nextButton =() => {
    return (
  <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
          onPress={() => verifyNavigate()}
        >
          <LinearGradient
            colors={[Colors.Grayish_blue,
              Colors.Oval_blue,
              Colors.Dark_blue]}
            style={styles.linearGradientStyle}
          >
            <Text 
            style={styles.nextText}>next</Text>
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
         )
    }


return (
<nextButton />

  )
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on your question, providing more details with error logs if any?

Comment: I edit my question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `nextButton` is just a function and not a component. **You can't create a component inside a component but you can create multiple components in a single file.**

you can call it as function in your MainScreen return

> `{nextButton()}`

If you want to use it as a component you need to move it outside the MainScreen Component body

```
export const NextButton = () => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
      onPress={() => verifyNavigate()}
    >
      <LinearGradient
        colors={[Colors.Grayish_blue, Colors.Oval_blue, Colors.Dark_blue]}
        style={styles.linearGradientStyle}
      >
        <Text style={styles.nextText}>next</Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export const MainScreen = () => {
  return <NextButton />
};
```

And do remember best practice is to use a component name starting with capital letter so rename `nextButton` with `NextButton`.

If this works for you kindly upvote the answer

Comment: what do you mean "move it outside the MainScreen".
show me please in code how do you do it and whats is diffrents between what i did ?

Comment: I have already added the snippet in the answer

Comment: its might be because of verifyNavigate() function, can you post the error log
Try commenting the onPress={() => verifyNavigate()} this line

Comment: can you tell me why my example is a function and not a component ? what the different between them ?

Comment: You can't create a component inside a component you are creating nextButton component inside MainScreen hence it is treated as a normal Function and not as the Component.

Comment: You can have multiple components inside a single file example snippet that I have provided. Your version of nextButton is inside MainScreen component body.